# How do you make HTML run instead of show html commands from a database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, nicedit

I am using nicEdit.js and it saves to the database like this:

```
<div align="center"><i>test</i><br></div><u><br><font size="5"><b>Become part of our team!</b></font><br></u>
```

From the database I retrieve it as $jobfulldesc.

This will show it correctly:

```
<?php
function unhtmlentities ($string) {
  $trans_tbl =get_html_translation_table (HTML_ENTITIES );
  $trans_tbl =array_flip ($trans_tbl );
  return strtr ($string ,$trans_tbl );
}
echo unhtmlentities($jobfulldesc); ?>
```

That just doesn't work if you try to add nicEdit into your javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
      var myNicEditor = new nicEditor();
      myNicEditor.setPanel('myInstance1');

 });
</script>
<div id="myInstance1"><?php echo unhtmlentities($jobfulldesc); ?></div>
```

or inside of:

```
<textarea><?php echo unhtmlentities($jobfulldesc); ?></textarea>
```

How do you make it be seen without the format of HTML inside of nicEdit from the database?

Comment: You want to http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php or do you want to http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php, or http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php or you might want to  http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php? i've read your question 3 times, can you show us your 'expected results' please?

Comment: It basically just is suppose to output in this example:    test

Become part of our team!

Comment: I wanted to pull it from the database so that the user can re-edit their mistakes.

Comment: Looks at he many example in the links i've put, it's all in PHP. Depending on your exact needs you might have to use one or another or many of those function and run a few test.

Comment: I have tried the html-entity-decode and it works until you put it into a textarea for nicEdit.  So the problem really lies within the nicEdit javascript and textareas not letting you html-entity-decode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the text from HTML using **Javascript** only:

```
function getText(htmlString) {
       const virtual = document.createElement('div');
       virtual.innerHTML = htmlString;
       return virtual.textContent
}
```

Assuming `htmlString` is coming from database and passing to javascript through PHP.

#### demo:

```js
function getText(htmlString) {
       const virtual = document.createElement('div');
       virtual.innerHTML = htmlString;
       return virtual.textContent
}

const retreivedHtml = `<div align="center"><i>test</i><br></div><u><br><font size="5"><b>Become part of our team!</b></font><br></u>`;

console.log(
   getText(retreivedHtml)
)
// inject it in the textarea
document.querySelector('textarea').value= getText(retreivedHtml)
```

```html
 <textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: How would you put this back into a html <textarea></textarea> or have nicEdit use it to re-edit it again?

Comment: I was trying this:   <textarea><script>getText(<?php echo $jobfulldesc ?>)</script></textarea>

Comment: nope! See the demo in the answer .. it includes that which is : `<script>document.querySelector('textarea').value= getText(<?php echo $jobfulldesc ?>)</script>`.

Comment: That works great! :)  I appreciate the clarification.  I just missed that last line originally.

Comment: Your r Welcome 